Automaticall generate pass through to child object function
I would like to automatically forward a function call to a child in python, so that the parent class has said function and then forwards the call to the child and returns the result to the caller. Something like this:
class child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 1

    def dosomething(self, a=1):
        print("child dosomething", a, self.b)
        return 'returning stuff'

class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = child()

    # I could do this for every func in child:
    def dosomething(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.child.dosomething()

p = parent()
p.dosomething()


Since I don't want to risk typos or forgetting to update the parent this should be done automatically and not like shown above, especially if child has lots of functions.
I was able to do something similar to this by implementing getattr for the parent class, but this way neither my IDE nor the interpreter knows about the methods in parent / child which is not what I want.
Another way I was exploring was to get all methods of the child using
def get_methods(x):
    return [
        [method, getattr(x, method)]
        for method in dir(x)
        if callable(getattr(x, method))
        if not method.startswith("_")
    ]

and then somehow attach them to my parent class.
I can do that using setattr(parent,'dosomething',func_from_get_methods(child))
and then call it the same way as before, but this wont work, since parent has no self.b.
So, is there any pythonic way to do this?
P.S. I'm not talking about subclassing.

should Parent() subclass Child()?

To clarify, you want to do this for any arbitrary function that is defined on child class? (since your code works for dosomething)

Yes exactly that what @matszwecja says. I don't want subclassing

If anyone ever stumbles over this "problem"...
After getting some sleep and some tinkering I've come up with a solution.
In principle the idea is twofold:

by subclassing Child I get all functions in my autocomplete
add_pass_through_functions then replaces these functions with a pass through, so that parent.dosomething is redirected to parent.child

(And if you are wording that add_pass_through_functions does accept multiple child classes, since child is interchangeable with different implementations of child which might add some functions)
My code:
def get_methods(x):
    # returns all methods of class x (or multiple classes)
    res = {}
    xs = x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]
    for x in xs:
        for method in dir(x):
            try:
                if callable(getattr(x, method)) and not method.startswith("_"):
                    res[method] = getattr(x, method)
            except:
                print(f'Skipping {method} due to error')
    return res


def add_pass_through_functions(parent_class, child_classes: list, child_variable_name: str):
    # adds all methods of the child_class(es) to the variable child_variable_name which belongs to parent_class
    methods = get_methods(child_classes)
    for name, method in methods.items():
        def wrap(func, doc):
            def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return getattr(getattr(self, child_variable_name), func)(*args, **kwargs)

            f.__doc__ = doc
            return f

        func = wrap(name, method.__doc__)
        setattr(parent_class, name, func)


class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def dosomething(self, a=1):
        print("child dosomething", a)
        return 'returning stuff'


class Parent(Child): # by subclassing Child I get all methods in the autocomplete
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = Child()


add_pass_through_functions(parent_class=Parent, child_classes=Child, child_variable_name='child')

parent = Parent()
parent.dosomething()

